# Problemas de integridad Referencial y como restaurar migraciones en Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, phpmyadmin

Hola tuve unos problemas de integridad referencial haciendo un modelo.
Basicamente tenia un articulo con una categoria y tags

Para tags cree otra tabla que posee el id del articulo y del tag, ya que puede contener mas de uno. Aqui me surgio el primer problema ya que si quiero borrar un articulo me olvide el onDelete cascade en esa tabla pivote

```
$table->foreign('articulo_id')->references('id')->on('articulos')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Esto me despertó la duda de que pasaba si borro una categoria, el categoria_id en articulo como hago para manejarlo, en principio me gustaria ponerle null y veo como lo manejo, ya que colocarle  un OnDelete, no me parece que si se borra una categoria, necesariamente tenga que borrar un articulo. Pero no encontré como hacerlo desde la migraciones en laravel o tengo q modificar el valor del nombre cuando hago el destroy?

Y una vez editadas las migraciones. Hay forma de restaurarlas sin borrar los datos de la base de datos?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con restaurar la migración? Volver a efectuar la última migración?

Comment: para modificar las migraciones en mi base de datos
Encontre en la documentacion php artisan migrate:refresh. seria este?

Comment: Ese es para regresar TODAS las migracionas y volver a ejecutarlas. Obviamente perderías toda la información dependiendo los comandos que ejecutes en `down()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asumiendo que tu llave foránea sea *nullable*, podrías usar `set null`:

```
$table->integer('articulo_id')->unsigned()->nullable();

$table->foreign('articulo_id')->references('id')->on('articulos')->onDelete('set null');
```

Un poco de documentación de MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html